# Xcodeのstoryboardでsize inspectorのConstraints指定したオブジェクトの大きさを把握したい

Tags: xcode, storyboard

XcodeのstoryboardでConstraintsで指定したオブジェクトの大きさを見ながら開発したいと思っています。
size inspectorのConstraintsで数字指定してもstoryboard上(Canvas)のオブジェクトには反映されません。逆に”Use canvas size”と指定するとCanvas上のサイズが反映されます。
WidthやHeightに数字指定するとCanvas上のオブジェクトに反映されるということをやりたいのですが、どこかに設定でもあるのでしょうか。
ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

----(設定状態追加) ----
[image: Constraints設定]
画面イメージを追加しました。右の方でConstraintsをUIWebViewに対し上下左右100pt設定していますが、Canvas上では反映されておらず右に174pt, 下に390pt設定された状態になっています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

制約で指定されている値を修正する場合、以下の手順でどうでしょうか？

[image: 制約の値を修正]

---

制約で指定されている値をフレームに反映する場合、以下の手順でどうでしょうか？

[image: 制約の値をフレームに反映]

Comment: 質問の仕方が悪かったです。失礼しました。ご回答いただいた2の値を変更しても、オブジェクトの見た目は変わらないのです。

Comment: こちらでは、Xcode 6.1.1(6A2008a)で2のConstantを変更、returnでオブジェクトの見た目も変わることを確認しました。もしかして、変更したいオブジェクトに複数の制約が重なってるとか、そういう状態では無いでしょうか？

Comment: 今朝、再びXCodeの画面を開くと反映されました。不思議ですが解決しました。

Comment: 制約の値をフレームに反映する説明を追加しました。これで上手くいけば、いちいち画面を開き直さなくても良くなるかと思います。